# Debugging gradle web application in Jetty

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gretty

I am new to Gradle. I am using Buildship in eclipse. My build.gradle looks like,

```
gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'
}
```

When I debug the application as, 'gretty -> appStartDebug', the console waits saying like,

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

My project is a web application with init as,

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/InitServlet", loadOnStartup=0)
public class InitServlet extends HttpServlet {
}

public static void initialize() {
 system.out.println("Initializing");
}
```

I have my break point in the sysout. Is this proper way of debugging gradle application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is waiting for your debugger process to attach to the socket.

1. Create a new [remote debugging session](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcremdbug.htm) in Eclipse
2. Execute gradle task `appStartDebug` and wait for message:

   `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`
3. Run your previously configured remote debug configuration in Eclipse
4. Stop debugging your web application with gradle task `appStop`

Read for more information and also on how to debug in IntelliJ IDEA [here](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/36#issuecomment-49309075).